# .width() returns 4 pixels too much

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div:

```
<div class="frame" id="layer1"> ... </div>
```

with the styling:

```
.frame {
    position: absolute;
    width: 380px;
    height: 280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#layer1  { background-color: red; color: #fff; }
```

But these are my results:

```
$(".frame").filter(":first").width(); // 384
$(".frame").filter(":first").outerWidth();  // 384
$(".frame").filter(":first").innerWidth();  // 384
```

I understand them all being the same since my padding and margins are 0, but where does this default 4px come from?

Comment: What is the width reported by FireBug/Chrome element inspector?

Comment: Try this: [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/) to make sure it is exactly 380px, even with padding.

Comment: I get 380 in Chrome, Firefox, and IE: http://jsbin.com/isehud Also note that there's no need to do the `.filter(":first")`, jQuery *getters* always only get from the first element in the set. (And if you *did* need to do it, `.first()` rather than `.filter(":first")` is probably a better way to go, or `.eq(0)`.)

Comment: [I can't reproduce it.](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/DTwqj/2/)

Comment: for me it is returning 380 in jsfiddle and Chrome. What browser(s) are you using and is this phenomenon unique to that/those browser/s or does it appear in other browsers as well?

Comment: If all .frame elements need to be exactly 380 pixels and you're css is clashing with other style rules, change the rule to `width: 380px !important;`

Comment: It's all my fault!! Thank you for the help. I had something else running an addition of 4 to the equation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved, thank you for you responses - it helped!

Had something else performing an addition to the equation. Feel stupid even asking this but your answers and questions did help me get to the bottom of it! I should have posted the entire script:

```
var layers = $(".frame");
console.log(layers);

var totalWidth = layers.size() + layers.filter(":first").innerWidth();
console.log(totalWidth);
```

As you see the problem lies in `layers.size() +` , it should have been multiplication and not addition and I should have seen it earlier.

Comment: *"Please read edit in question for conclusion."* It's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). The correct way to do that is to leave the question as a question, and post the answer in an answer. Or in this  case, as it was just a mistake, you can flag your question asking the moderators to remove it entirely if you like.